# Android APK path is not specified for module

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-studio, building

I have a problem. When i try to launch my project i've got error :

```
"ERROR: APK path is not specified for module"
```

I follow to this answer [APK path is not specified for module "Example-Example"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16722651/apk-path-is-not-specified-for-module-example-example) but that no give me result. Any more ideas?

Comment: did you try uninstalling, and re-installing. plus rebuilding the apk

Comment: @Doomsknight, yes i did rebuildg. Uninstalling, and re-installing doesn't available for me because IDE make apk, but not deploy him to device, because doesn't have a path for saving `*.apk*

Comment: Which version of studio are you using ?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

1. Open **Project structure**
2. Click on **Modules** tab
3. Expand your project and click on ***Android***
4. On right side click on **Packaging** tab (**Compiler** on older versions of Android Studio)
5. Look for **APK path** field
6. Click on <kbd>...</kbd> and choose your project root folder (that contains **bin/gen/res/** folders)
7. Copy path into your clipboard
8. Close choose path dialog
9. Paste copied path into APK path field
10. Add to path text **\bin**
11. Click <kbd>Apply</kbd> and <kbd>OK</kbd>

In the end you must have a path:

`D:\<path to your project root>\bin`

Try to build your project

***Note:** For Android Studio use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24304786)*

Comment: What version of IntelliJ are these instructions targeting? I don't see a Compiler tab (step 4)

Comment: @StealthRabbi use a answer below.

Comment: Well, why do you say "For Android Studio use this[link] answer". Your answer is meant for Android Studio or IntelliJ??

Comment: @StealthRabbi is mixed solution for both IDE. BUT. In some versions in AS this is solution not worked, so i added a link.

Comment: For me, I had to add the filename of the APK that I wanted. So it ended up being `D:\<path to your project root>\bin\appname-debug-unaligned.apk`

Answer (score 16):

Could not use the accepted answer in my Android Studio (0.6.1) because I couldn't find the "Compiler" tab. I suppose that this structure is for Intelij. Nevertheless, it pointed me to the right solution:

My Project included some LIB modules besides the main APK module and by setting all modules to use the same Compiler output directory fixed the error. In order to do so you just need to follow these steps:

1. Open **Project structure** (F4 on one of the modules in the project explorer)
2. Click on **Project** tab on the left
3. Define **"Project compiler output:"** as *YOUR_PROJECT_PATH*\out (or any folder you want)
4. Click on **Modules** tab on the left
5. Go over all your modules and verify that under the **Paths** tab the Compiler output is set to **"Inherit project compile output path"**
6. Thats it...

Comment: Perfect Answer! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5):

Another reason could be that the Output Directory is not set to a valid directory. Note that relative paths are not supported, at least in IntelliJ 14.

Project Structure (Cmd-;) > Modules > Paths:

[image]

Set Compiler output to "Use module compile output path", then choose/create the desired output directory for the APK.

Comment: Thanks - this worked - I'm also using IntelliJ 14.  Inheriting the output path didn't - needed to manually set a path for each module.

Answer (score 2):

Having this problem, if you want to build a project from other sources like github or another PC, try to close current project, and use "New -> import project" not "Open" to sync project with gradle files.

Answer (score 1):

Note - I had same issue here,  It seems intellij caches a lot of stuff. All my settings were right in the UI but I had renamed the .iml file using the refactor feature because of a spelling error. it left a dangling reference to the old module spelling in the .idea/modules file with along with the new one it created and did not update the build path (cached?) I had to invalidate the caches, hand edit the ,idea/modules.xml file to delete the entries ( all of them to be safe with intellij closed ) then restarted intellij and re-imported the .iml files.

I also re-booted the android device.

Probably overkill but this solved the problem in my case.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running a 64-bit distribution on your development machine, you need to install additional packages first. For **Ubuntu 13.10** (Saucy Salamander) and **above**, install the libncurses5:i386, libstdc++6:i386, and zlib1g:i386 packages using apt-get:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386 zlib1g:i386
```

For **earlier** versions of Ubuntu, install the ia32-libs package using apt-get:

```
apt-get install ia32-libs
```