# How to debug/launch Android app in intelliJ (maven)

Tags: android, maven, intellij-idea

I have an multimodule application build by maven, one of the module is Android app. From "build side" everything seems to be ok, APK is built etc. I want to launch or debug this app in android emulator or device but here have some issues. In standard way (Gradle-aware Make) there is an Multidex error. I added multidex support dependecies, checked multidex option in IDE but with no result. After that I had read that better option is to use Maven so I changed launch profile to "Run Maven Goal" (with options "clean install"), as always everything seems to be OK but then there is a message "install failed, invalid APK"... but why ? Im abble to install that "generated APK" manually on the device but with IDE there is no such possibility. Have You ever met with such situation?

Answer (score 0):

For proper integration with emulators just use Android Studio - it's a flavor of intellij

https://developer.android.com/studio

Comment: OK i tried to launch app module in Android Studio but is that possibile to run here an Maven project just like that ?  Now I have a problem "Android APK path is not specified for module" i tried to fix it by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21281445/android-apk-path-is-not-specified-for-module with no results... please remember that app is in maven not gradle

Comment: @MattiahIT here's an article i found - seems pretty straight forward to use maven https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBuildMaven/article.html

That has a lot of info, scroll about half way down the page for the maven specific stuff

Answer (score 0):

why you want to launch your app on intellij instead use android studio

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).