# Android SDK is not specified

Tags: android

I use Intellij Idea 12. Some days ago all works fine, but now I get error

`Android Source Generator: [facebook] Android SDK is not specified`.
Project settings you can see on a picture. I try to rebuld project but it does not help me.

[image: project settings]

Comment: Same question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6079004/upgrade-intellij-to-10-5-and-android-build-fails-android-sdk-not-specified , check your IntelliJ Idea settings.


Edit: By the way, why are you using JDK 1.7?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solution is in   [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6079004/upgrade-intellij-to-10-5-and-android-build-fails-android-sdk-not-specified) post. In my case it was problem with Android platform, i change it from 4.1.2 to 4.3 and now all works fine